# Problem with my usercontrol listview fill data from msaccess

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, user-controls

I created  listview ms activex by vb.net to my access database
i add that code in vb.net  to fill my listview

```
Public Sub FillListview(ByVal CurrntDb As String)
          Dim conn As OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
    Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ds As DataSet
    Dim itemcoll(100) As String
    ListView1.View = View.Details
    ListView1.GridLines = True
    ListView1.Items.Clear()
    conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source =" & CurrntDb)
    Dim strQ As String = String.Empty
    strQ = "SELECT Accounts.ID AS [م], Customers.Customer  AS [العميل], Accounts.Debit  AS [مدين], Accounts.Credit  AS [دائن], Accounts.Dates  AS [التاريخ], Accounts.Notes  AS [البيان] FROM Accounts INNER JOIN Customers ON Accounts.Customer_ID = Customers.Customer_ID;"
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(strQ, conn)
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
    ds = New DataSet
    conn.Open()
    da.Fill(ds)
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim j As Integer = 0
    ' adding the columns in ListView
    For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
        ListView1.Columns.Add(ds.Tables(0).Columns(i).ColumnName.ToString())
    Next
    'Now adding the Items in Listview
    For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
        For j = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
            itemcoll(j) = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)(j).ToString()
        Next
        Dim lvi As New ListViewItem(itemcoll)
        ListView1.Items.Add(lvi)
        ListView1.Refresh()
    Next
    conn.Close()
 
End Sub
```

and regestir it in my access database
and call it in access code by that code

```
    Dim xlist As New AForTestListviewBySedo.UserControl1
    Call xlist.FillListview("C:\Users\Elsayed\Desktop\New folder\mydb.accdb")
```

but they give me nothing  not error but nothing

I tested that code in usercontrol by add button in it
button works good

What can I do ?

Comment: What is `AForTestListviewBySedo`? You're creating a new instance of your UserControl: are you also showing it somewhere, adding it to a Form?

Comment: <ProgId("AForTestListviewBySedo")>
<ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)>
Public Class UserControl1
    Public Const EventsId As String = "50965EF1-E501-42E9-8E8A-BCDBFA44DE1E"
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

Comment: i add refrence from tlb file but not fill my listview

Comment: For test  sub i add Msgbox (okay saved) in Public Sub FillListview.msgbox show good but listview not fill

Comment: there is no hope ?

Answer (score 0):

the solution is with my code in access to call record
i need to set object at first
the correct code is

```
Option Explicit
  Option Compare Database
Public listv As MsAccessListviewACX1_00.UCBySedo
Public Sub LoadListview()
Set listv = Me.UCBySedo9.Object
listv.FillListview ("C:\Users\Elsayed\Desktop\New folder\mydb.accdb")
End Sub
Private Sub Command115_Click()
Call LoadListview
End Sub
```